# I can't add table from json object in html

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
getJSON('http://localhost:63322/logs',
function(err, data) {
  if (err !== null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {

    //var myObj = JSON.parse(data);
  //  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.ad_soyad;


items_table = document.getElementById('items_table');
for(var ctr = 0; ctr < data.length; ctr++)
{
    items_table.innerHTML+= '<tr><td>' + data.data[ctr].uid + '</td><td>' +data.data[ctr].ad_soyad + '</td></tr>';
}

  }






      <form id="form">
    <table id='items_table' border=1>
  <tr><th colspan='2'>liste</th></tr>
  <tr><th>uid</th><th>ad_soyad</th></tr>
</table>
```

in these codes ı can't show up the table. I have no problem with my json object.I can show the json object but I can't show this object in my table.How can I solve this problem?

my json object is

{"data":[{"uid":2,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":6,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":6,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":10,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":16,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":190,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":200,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":200,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":220,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"},{"uid":4,"ad_soyad":"gg"}]}

thank you for your helps....

Comment: `for(var ctr = 0; ctr < data.data.length; ctr++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `data` is the parent object having another `data` as property and this `data` is actually the array here. So, you just need to replace:

```
for(var ctr = 0; ctr < data.length; ctr++)
```

with this:

```
for(var ctr = 0; ctr < data.data.length; ctr++)
```